# Jquery On instead of Live for dynamic inputs

Tags: jquery, jquery-on

I have this code...

```
// Display number of pixels left from nav width
$('.inputs input').live('keyup',function() {
    var nav_width = $('#nav-width').val();
    var sumOfVals = 0;
    $('.inputs input').each(function () {
    sumOfVals = sumOfVals + parseInt($(this).val());
});
sumOfVals = nav_width - sumOfVals;
    $('#px-left em').html(sumOfVals);
});
```

It needs to be executed on the keyup event of dynamically added input fields but I want to use the 'on' event. Is this possible? I have tried replacing 'live' with 'on' but it didn't work.

Comment: I would have been interested to see how you tried to replace it, but seems like somebody has already written it for you. Get used to reading the documentation, which has [explicit directions](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just replace `live` with `on`. If you read the docs about [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) you'll see this:

```
.on( events [, selector] [, data], handler(eventObject) )
```

So by following that you'd use `on` like this:

```
$('.closest-parent').on('keyup', '.inputs input', function () { ... })
```

`.closest-parent` is the closest parent element to `.inputs`. By using the closest parent instead of just `document` you improve performance.

Comment: You can replace it, simply attach it on `document` - `live` does basically the same. Whether it is a good idea or not is a different topic :).

Comment: And I agree with that. I just argued the way you said it: `You can't just replace live with on`, which is simply not true.

Comment: @bažmegakapa - You _can't_ just replace `.live` with `.on` in the sense of doing a find/replace and expecting it to work (which is, I'd be willing to bet, what the OP probably tried). But obviously if you allow for the different syntax of `.on` you can achieve the same effect.

Comment: @nnnnnn Oh, I get it now - misinterpreted. I'm not the one who downvoted though, I'd be happy to see the reason myself.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.inputs input', function() {
    var nav_width = $('#nav-width').val();
    var sumOfVals = 0;
    $('.inputs input').each(function () {
    sumOfVals = sumOfVals + parseInt($(this).val());
});
```